# Angular search using regex

Tags: angularjs

I have a search option in my application and when i search a zipcode , the entered value is found , but it does not search from the beginning (i.e) when i search "700" , ("2700" and "33700") both are found , but i need the zipcode starting from "700" (e.g "70035") . Is there any way to search like this?

My code:

public filter(filterText: string) {

```
let filteredTreeData;

if (filterText) {

  filteredTreeData = this.treeData.filter(d => d.text.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1);

  Object.assign([], filteredTreeData).map(ftd => {

    let str = (<string>ftd.code);

    while (str.lastIndexOf('.') > -1) {

      if (filteredTreeData.findIndex(t => t.code === str) === -1) {

        const obj = this.treeData.find(d => d.code === str);

        if (obj) {

          filteredTreeData.push(obj);

          console.log("filteredTreeData",filteredTreeData)

        }

      }

    }

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `str.startsWith()` like below.

```
const obj = this.treeData.find(d => str.startsWith(d.code));
```

but remember `.find()` will return only the first value of the array, that matches the search criteria. try `filter()` instead.

Comment: Tried this . But it is not working

Comment: can you post the `treeData` data structure? Do you still receive all the strings which do not start with the passed string?

Comment: And one thing what will be the search text you passed as `filterText`?